# High-dimensional indexing in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I would like to grab tensor `v1`'s third dim according to indices in tensor `indices`. I tried `torch.take` and `torch.gather`, but no go. See example:

```
import torch
v1 = torch.randn((1,35,20,200))
indices = torch.randint(0, 20, (1,35,20))
out = torch.gather(v1, 2, indices)
```

This gives an error as `v1` and `incides` dimensions don't match. Out should be of shape `[1,35, 20, 200]`. How would I do that in PyTorch?